# Octal to Decimal with (string) inputs in Python

Tags: python

Am stuck with some code. Am trying to write a function to translate octal to decimal accepting a string containing octal data (either a single number or a sequence of numbers separated by spaces) using loops and logic to return a string that contains one or more decimal numbers separated by spaces.

So far I have:

```
def decode(code):
  decimal = 0
  code = code.split(" ")
  l = len(code) 
  for i in range (l):
    octal = len(i)
    for x in range (octal):
      digit_position = x - 1
      decimal += pow(8, digit_position) * int(x)
result = str(decimal)
```

Produces an error. Any ideas?

Comment: What error? Please post full traceback.

Comment: Is code an integer, if so you can not use split().

Comment: Can we have the expected output?

Comment: Also `octal = len(i)` you cannot find the length of an integer.

Answer (score 2):

`int` takes an optional second argument (which defaults to 10): the base of the number to convert from. IIUC, you could just use:

```py
def decode(code):
    return str(int(code, 8)).replace("", " ")
```

Comment: The OP's question is a bit hard to follow, but from what I understand I would expect something like `return ' '.join(str(int(x, 8)) for x in code.split())`

Answer (score 0):

Explanation in code's comments:

```
def decode(code):
    code = code.split(' ')  # list of elements to convert
    code = [str(int(num, 8)) for num in code]  # convert using builtin int with second parameter - base
    return ' '.join(code)  # Return converted values as string
```

Comment: Why are you splitting on spaces twice?

Comment: I wasn't using first line at first, but then I thought it would be more helpful with more comments, thanks for pointing that out @MattDMo :)